# What are the right practices of using Apache Solr with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, solr

I am using **Apache Solr 6.3.0** and **MongoDB 3.4** for `advance text search` features. I have successfully, `synced mongodb with solr cores` using **mongo-connector 2.5** and **solr doc manager**.

I want to know the `right way and practices to use solr with mongo` and I have some issues that I need help on:

**1)**. Now that my `data is available both in mongo database and also indexed and stored in Solr cores`, should I now `query Solr all the time` ? Or should I `query solr for text search` only and perform `rest of the queries` on mongo ?

**2)**. Is there some way I could perform powerful `search directly on mongo database using the indexing done by Solr` ?

**3)**. I have some collections that contain `deeply nested json data` and MongoDb supports them well. Solr `indexes and stores` such data in `flattened form`.But, I want to `maintain the original nested json format` in `query response`. Is this something I can achieve with Solr ?

Other `suggestions about good practices` of using solr with mongoDb will be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If it makes sense to just query Solr, do that. If it makes sense to query Solr for certain data, do that. It depends on your use case, but if any query can be answered with the data in Solr, it's perfectly fine to use that for everything. That'll probably allow a more efficient use of your caches.
2. No, not that I know of.
3. Not really. Solr isn't well suited for nested JSON (even if you have parent/child documents, it's something you'll have to manually handle in every situation and will require special casing all over).

   In those situations you can use Solr for querying, get the ids back and then retrieve the actual documents from mongo with their JSON structure intact. In that case you can leave most fields as non-stored in Solr.